# Angular как сделать что бы одновременно на странице работало 2 контроллера

Tags: javascript, angularjs

У меня есть роутер который загружает тело сайта, есть шапка которая грузится всегда. Мне нужно что бы у шапки был свой контроллер, а у тела свой.
Можно ли это сделать и как?

Мой текущий код, роутер работает, а шапка нет.

```
//app.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies',
    'myApp.main',
    'myApp.navbar',
]);

app.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);

//main.js
angular.module('myApp.main', ['ngRoute'])
    .config([
        '$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'js/main/main.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            });
        }
    ])
    .controller('MainCtrl', [
        '$location', '$http', '$scope', '$cookies', function ($location, $http, $scope, $cookies) {
            ......
        }
    ]);

//navbar.js
angular.module('myApp.navbar', [])

    .controller('NavbarCtrl', [
        '$scope', '$cookies', function ($scope, $cookies) {
             ...............
        }
    }]);

//index.html
<body ng-app='myApp'>
<nav ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
  тут шапка и контроллер NavbarCtrl тут не работет
</nav>

<div ng-view></div> тут загружается тело

<script src="./js/app.js"></script>
<script src="./js/navbar.js"></script>
<script src="./js/main/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Если хотите использовать именно этот плагин для роутинга. Тогда смотрите сюда http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061540/can-i-pass-multiple-controllers-in-routeprovider-when-in-angularjs

Comment: Если же готовы поменять плагин тогда берите вот этот https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router . Там все хорошо расписано как и куда.

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что не работает? можешь сделать [mcve] пример? например на [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

Comment: @Grundy ну потому что у меня не работает ) Я попробую позже на plnkr правда у меня с ним были какие то проблемы с подключением ангуляра.

Comment: @YaroslavZaika спасибо ui-router то, что надо.